# Validate/Deployment ARM Template in Visual Studio with Power Shell 7

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-2019, azure-resource-manager

I would like to validate/deploy my ARM Template in Visual Studio 2019 via Power Shell 7.

What I have done:
right click on Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 -> open with -> Add -> in Program (C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe) -> set as default

but still if I would like to validate my ARM PRojekt via rigth click on it. It uses Windows Power Shell !!!

Why I would like to use PowerShell7 is that I want to use AZ libraries instead of RM. ( I have changed my Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 default power shell code to az).

Can some one tell me what should I do to run my Deploy Script via Power Shell 7?

Comment: We can open a PowerShell session with PowerShell 7 to run the script. If you want to validate arm template, we can use the command Test-AzResourceGroupDeployment to do that. If you want to deploy template, we can run the command \Deploy-AzTemplate.ps1 -ArtifactStagingDirectory . -Location "" -TemplateFile "" -TemplateParametersFile ""

Comment: Do you have any other concerns

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, we can open a PowerShell session with PowerShell 7 to run the script. If you want to validate arm template, we can use the command `Test-AzResourceGroupDeployment` to do that. If you want to deploy template, we can run the command `\Deploy-AzTemplate.ps1 -ArtifactStagingDirectory . -Location "" -TemplateFile "" -TemplateParametersFile ""`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/create-visual-studio-deployment-project#deploy-project-to-azure).